# How put an element more close to a html label

Tags: html, css, label

I need to create an element (div or span) more closer to a label created for an input field.
My problem is that the label width seems related to the input field width therefore, if i add a div immediately after an HTML label, that element will be created at the end of space occupied by the input box.
My question is: how can i move the div element more closer to the label text without using fixed position coordinates?

with my code i obtain something like:

```
Example label         XX
========================
========================
```

i need something like:

```
Example label  XX
======================
======================
```

that is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div id="spinner" style="float: right; visibility: visible;">XX</div>
    <label for="text_sample">Example Text</label>
    <label>
    <input type="text" id="input_sample" name="xxxx" value="" style="width:180px" />    
    </label>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
label{
    display: block;    
}
```

for your convenience I've created a [Fiddler demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ2Ep/):

Thank you

Comment: I used `float: left` on both the XX and the label. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/zQ2Ep/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <label for="text_sample" class="left">Example Text</label>
    <div id="spinner" class="left">XX</div>
    <label>
        <input type="text" id="input_sample" name="xxxx" value="" />
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: block;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
#input_sample {
    width:180px;
}
#spinner {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fGLy/